When did closure types finally became structural types?
There once was a long disscusion going on whether closure types should be considered as structural types or not (essentially determining whether they would be eligible as NTTPs). An elaborated post about this, made by user dfrib, can be found here.
The initial concern about this seemed to be raised by Zhihao Yuan, back in March 2022. This ended up becoming defect report CWG 2542, which was accepted by a working group meeting in June 2023. The proposed resolution of that defect report was approved and it very clearly stated that closure types are not structural types.
This change was reflected in many versions of the C++ Working Draft, at least all the way up to N4971. The passage of interest being listed under [expr.prim.lambda.closure]/3. This is also what people will find when looking up the cppreference entry about lambdas, which references defect report CWG 2542 at the bottom of the page.
However, in the more recent C++ Working Draft version N4981, passage [expr.prim.lambda.closure]/3 now reads:

The closure type is not an aggregate type (9.4.2); it is a structural
type (13.2) if and only if the lambda has no lambda-capture.

Which seems to revert the approved resolution of defect report CWG 2542. Should this defect report now be considered obsolete? And, by which meeting/decision/paper did closure types now become structural types?

I do not see this as a reversion but a revision.  They qualified that it is structural in a non-capture case which is very sensible and state that otherwise it is not.

Curious: do you have a reason (or are you aware of a reason) why a captureless lambda shouldn't be a structural type?

Are captureless lambdas structural types?

Well, if the change is in the post-Tokyo draft but not the immediately preceding one, it's probably something in the Tokyo meeting?

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p3196r0.html#2845

The point of CWG2542 was that capture lists are not public memebers & automatically strip the closure type from being aggregate & consequently structural. But the special case of empty capture was missing from the discussion. N4981 addressed this defect by stating that empty capture list makes the closure type empty,  and consequently structural. This is an exception to the general case - just like implicit conversion of empty capture closure to function pointers. One motivating example would be unique_ptr with an immediate inline deleter definition.


And, by which meeting/decision/paper did closure types now become structural types?

This was CWG2845 whose proposed and accepted resolution was to make a captureless lambda a structural type.
This can be seen from CWG2845:

Make the closure type of a captureless lambda a structural type
Issue 2542 (approved in June, 2023) made all closure types not be structural types, i.e. unsuitable for use as non-type template parameters. This causes an inconsistency with the treatment of the pointer-to-function conversion for closure types with no captures:
Proposed resolution (approved by CWG 2024-02-02):
Change in 7.5.5.2 [expr.prim.lambda.closure] paragraph 3 as follows:

The closure type is not an aggregate type (9.4.2 [dcl.init.aggr]) and not ; it is a structural type (13.2 [temp.param]) if and only if the lambda has no lambda-capture. An implementation may define the closure type differently from ...



The history here was pretty odd.
CWG 2542 was an issue submitted by Zhihao Yuan wondering about the validity of this example:
template <auto V>
void foo() {}

void bar() {
  foo<[i = 3] { return i; }>();
}

Since the rules for structural types require all public members and the data members of a lambda are unnamed and unspecified - so it's not clear if they're public or not.
Core decided to resolve this issue by going all out and rejecting all lambdas from consideration from being structural - regardless of whether they have capture or not.
So then I submitted CWG 2845 building on top of Zhihao's example, pointing out that:
template <auto V>
void foo() {}

void bar() {
  foo<[i = 3] { return i; }>();   // #1: error
  foo<[]{}>();                    // #2: error
  foo<+[]{}>();                   // #3: OK, a function pointer is a structural type
}

Which was then resolved to consider lambdas with no capture as being structural.
This latter issue was adopted in the Tokyo meeting in March 2024 (which is where the current wording quoted in OP comes from), which you can think of as reverting/fixing the incorrect resolution of the former issue.

I can see why the standard wouldn't want to be overly specific when it comes to the implementation details of closure types. And, therefore defining capturing lambdas not to be structural types. However, I don't really see why the example you provided is such a compelling counter argument. Since function pointers already meet the requirements of structural types, and captureless lambdas already provide an easy way to convert them to such. Why go through the trouble of changing the rules to specifically define captureless lambdas to be structural types? --

-- A rather subtle but also significant difference between #2 and #3, is that each invocation of #2 leads to a new template instantiation of foo. But what benefit does this exactly provide?

@303 Why go through the trouble of allowing lambdas to be used as non-type template parameters? Because it's obviously useful - and requiring conversion to function pointer to accomplish this is both silly and pointlessly limiting - generic lambdas cannot be converted to a function pointer like this.

@303 The reason I originally brought up this issue in 2020 is that if lambdas are allowed to be used as non-type template parameter, then it opens up another can of worm for stateful meta-programming, a yet to be formally resolved topic going as far back as 2015 via CWG 2118. Whilst hidden friend injection is both brittle and a very niche technique, abusing lambbas as non-type template parameters for stateful meta-programming is not as far-fetched.

... I'm a bit concerned about the non-intended abuse potential of stateful meta-programming becoming more wide-spread due to this new "tool" (Hyrum's law, in a sense), something I highlighted in a follow-up Q&A.

@dfrib I guess in general I'm less concerned about "non-intended abuse potential of stateful meta-programming" than I am about "intended use potential of just passing functions around in normal ways"

@dfrib "... if lambdas are allowed to be used as non-type template parameter, then it opens up another can of worm for stateful meta-programming ..." Like, safely checking if a type is complete, for example? However, it's not allowing lambdas as NTTPs that opens this can of worms, but rather allowing lambda expressions in unevaluated contexts. Because even when closure types are defined not to be structural types, there is still the option of simply doing: template<typename = decltype([]{})>
